# nginx rewrite issues

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I just switched from apache to nginx, just for testing and I experience the following problem. I am using this config for nginx

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
```

}
Now I have a php script makethumbs.php that automatically resize images displayed on my website. With apache, works just fine. With nginx I get this error:

```
2011/12/29 15:13:17 [error] 15548#0: *9 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/makethumbs.php/0737438664-22.jpg" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 193.138.192.81, server: www.escortele.eu, request: "GET /makethumbs.php/0737438664-22.jpg?width=48&height=64&image=/members/escorte/0737438664-22.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "escortele.eu:88", referrer: "http://escortele.eu:88/"
```

The problem is that it sees makethumbs.php as a directory and it should be a script not a directory.

I can't figure it out what rewrite rule to use, only for makethumbs.php so it acts like a script and not like a directory.

Comment: this url does not match your location regexp

Comment: sorry but i am not sure i understand what you mean... i have no regex defined for nginx and also no regex defined for that url in .htaccess file when using apache as webserver.

Comment: `~ \.php$` : `/usr/share/nginx/html/makethumbs.php/0737438664-22.jpg` ends with `.jpg` and not `.php`. You'll need a rewriterule before, rewriting it to `makethumbs.php?0737438664-22.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

You should have pasted the rest of your configuration file because what you pasted has nothing to do with what you want.

That error is because you have "try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;" somewhere in your config. You need to remove the $uri/ from that to fix the error you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

That part is good. You need it.

Since you didn't post your entire config I can't be sure what you're problem is, but I can tell you what my problem was in the same type of situation. Following the recomendation of others, I had a location defined for image files as follows:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
     expires max;
     log_not_found off;
}
```

That was the problem. Because Nginx uses the most specific location that matches, the URL ending with .jpg would match this location and this location doesn't tell it to use index.php. I just got rid of this location and it worked.

Additional tips:

- define your root in the server block and not in location blocks.
- I don't think you don't need "fastcgi_index  index.php;"
- You don't need to hard-code your document root:

change

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
```

to

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I am using for thumbnails: http://escorte.pro:88/makethumbs.txt

My nginx config is as follows: http://escorte.pro:88/nginx.txt

The error I get is:

2014/08/27 14:59:07 [error] 20986#0: *86 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/escorte.pro/makethumbs.php/0737835261-79.jpg" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 83.166.220.234, server: escorte.pro, request: "GET /makethumbs.php/0737835261-79.jpg?width=48&height=64&image=/members/escorte/0737835261-79.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "escorte.pro:88", referrer: "http://escorte.pro:88/"
2014/08/27 14:59:07 [error] 20986#0: *87 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/escorte.pro/makethumbs.php/0743844296-60.jpg" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 83.166.220.234, server: escorte.pro, request: "GET /makethumbs.php/0743844296-60.jpg?width=48&height=64&image=/members/escorte/0743844296-60.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "escorte.pro:88", referrer: "http://escorte.pro:88/"

The makethumbs.php script works perfectly fine on apache

Any clues?

I hope this info si more complete than the previous...